# Why direction of the curve does not matter in linear integral in respect to arc?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

So i know that the linear integral in respect to arc is the area and no matter which direction we go with the curve we will get the same result. But could anyone show me a proof that does not rely on the geometric interpretation. I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Basically, it’s because $\|\mathbf v\|=\|-\mathbf v\|$.

Answer (score 0):

One way to define a line integral is as the limit of Riemann sums: $$
\int_\Gamma\omega=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}\omega(P_i)[\mathbf v_i],
$$ where the points $P_i$ are a subdivision of the path $\Gamma$ and the vectors $\mathbf v_i$ are the displacements between adjacent points, i.e., $\mathbf v_i=P_iP_{i+1}$ (with the mesh size approaching zero in the limit, of course). Since by linearity $\omega[-\mathbf v]=-\omega[\mathbf v]$, the ordinary line integral depends on the orientation of $\Gamma$.

For the absolute line integral, we use the *lengths* of those displacement vectors instead, that is, $$\int_\Gamma f\;ds=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}f(P_i)s_i,$$ where $s_i=\|\mathbf v_i\|$. Since $\|-\mathbf v\|=\|\mathbf v\|$, this sum clearly doesn’t depend on the orientation of $\Gamma$.